# How do we install the authorize.net patch using composer

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

Magento CE 2.1.9
Composer Based Download (Authorize.net Direct Post Signature Key Patch)

Sorry for such a basic question but what is the syntax to install the patch?...using composer.

Do I put the file in the "magentodocroot/vendor" directory then magentouser@magentodocroot>composer install vendor/Auth.net.md5.composer-2019-02-27-11-51-12.patch 
Insert downloads access tokens

Answer (score 1):

It's a patch, not a composer package, so there is no composer install command to run.

Download the appropriate patch from Magento. Upload that to your server and place it in an easy to reference place, like your users home directory. Then just cd to your Magento install directory (where the vendor and app directories are) and run this: `patch -p0 < path/to/uploaded/file.patch`

Answer (score 0):

You can install it via composer using the cweagans plugin that allows using a patch file. However, the format of the file released by Authorize/Magento is not in standard 'github' format. (you need to prefix all of the path references in the patch file with "a/" for the original pre-patched version and "b/" for all of the post-patched)
I also noted on mine that although I downloaded the one that said it was compatible with my version of Magneto 2 (v2.2.4) the file Model/DirectPost.php was offset by -12 lines for all patch references.

I should also add that after patching our magento, it's still throwing errors and not properly processing a credit card payment.

SW